# Linux: Copy single line in Input File #1 X amount of times based on Input File #2's line count into an appended File #3

Tags: linux, bash, shell, append, concatenation

I must be awful at looking this up the internet.

Basically I have a two separate files outputting to a new file. File 1 will contain one line "ABCD", File 2 will contain an unknown amount of lines, let's call it X, of "123.456.789.WXY". I want to do wc - l File 2, take that amount paste X times of ABCD and concatenate it to 123.456.789.WXY in a new file.

Example File 1:

```
ABCD
```

Example File 2:

```
123.456.789.WXY

123.456.789.WX1

123.456.789.WX2

123.456.789.WX3
```

Output File:

```
ABCD 123.456.789.WXY 

ABCD 123.456.789.WX1 

ABCD 123.456.789.WX2 

ABCD 123.456.789.WX3
```

Script:

```
echo "Please select from the the following options:"
echo "<1> ABCD"
echo "<2> EFGH"
echo "<3> IJKL"
echo "<4> MNOP"
echo -n "Input your selection and press [Enter]:"
read input
if echo "$input" | grep -iq "1"; then

numoflines=$(wc -l < Desktop/input.txt)
         for i in {1..$numoflines}
         do
             echo "ABCD $i" > Desktop/output.txt
         done
 exit
```

Instead,I get ABCD{1..4} in my output file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this output as, brace expansion does not interpolate variables.

```
for i in {1..$numoflines}
```

You can refer to brace expansion doc [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

In your case, you can use below version of for loop. It is classic C style loop, more suited for looping n number of times.

```
for (( c=1; c<=$numoflines; c++ ))
do
   echo "Welcome $c times"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple while loop to read the second file and store the single entry from first file in a variable:

```
file1_var=$(< file1)

while read -r line
do
  echo "$file1_var $line"
done<file2>file3
```